# Design of WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm building an wpf application which consists of a mysql database, entity framework, wpf using the mvvm pattern. There's already a model based on the database already exists, those objects are not domain objects.

As I see it i'm going to have alot of "look-a-like" objects and alot of mappings. E.g a Customer object from the database, a Customer domain object, a Customer object used in the viewmodel which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

My questions are:

1. Is it common to have all those "look-a-like" objects and alot of mappings or should the domain objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged (where its needed) ?
2. Should the viewmodels have access to my repositories using dependency injection or should I've a layer between my viewmodels and repositories ?

Please post your experiences or any relevant links.

Thanks.

Comment: We don't do links, so asking for them isn't allowed.  For more info on why, visit [meta]. As to your question... it's a bit whiteboard.  SO is keyboard, [programmers.se] is whiteboard.  However, I don't think you'll get a satisfactory answer to your questions. 1. whatever floats your boat. You should KISS 2. whatever floats your boat. You'll still have to inject the layer, so why write it? KISS it again.

Comment: Agree with Will re the question format but here's my $0.02 anyway: 1) The view isn't the only component that can benefit from property change notification so I use Castle Dynamic Proxy to automatically inject it into my domain entities. 2) Agree with the KISS principle, I usually use Ninject and scope session variables (and thus repositories) to pages. The article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx uses NHibernate but should be relevant to what you're trying to do.